# Reading Excel Data With Javascript

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, javascript, excel, file

I am needing to instantiate a File object containing the contents of an excel spreadsheet that is stored on the SharePoint site. It is contained within SitePages/data/TestRoles.xlsx, so I figured the path I should pass it is "data/TestRoles.xlsx". My code to create the file is then:

```
var f = new File([""], "data/TestRoles.xlsx");
```

But that ended up note working and I'm not sure why, I get a "Unsupported file NaN" error. What is the correct way to instantiate a File object with a file stored on my SharePoint site? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I ended up creating a script to convert my .xlsx to a .txt in csv form and then upload it to sharepoint, retrieve it with an XMLHttpRequest. Works just fine. If anyone thinks this is a bad way to solve this let me know, and feel free to answer the original question.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a library like [ExcelPlus](http://aymkdn.github.io/ExcelPlus/) (that I have created) to help you reading your Excel file.

With ExcelPlus you have an example:

```
var ep=new ExcelPlus();
// we call openRemote()
ep.openRemote("/path/tp/your/file.xlsx", function(passed) {
  if (!passed) alert("Error: impossible to load the remote file");
  else console.log(ep.selectSheet(1).readAll()) // show the content of the first sheet
})
```